# How to extract aspx files from an MDF?

Tags: sql, sharepoint, mdf

Recently my Windows Sharepoint Services 3.0 server went down, and all I have is the mdf and ldf. Am I correct in assuming that the aspx files are embedded in these database files? I have attached the db to a local sql, and have access to it. However, I need to access some of the aspx files that were created in sharepoint. How do I go about extracting these files? I've been using MS SQL Manager Studio Express to sift through the data. However, the ASPX pages that have the real content (not the structure of SP) is needed.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all your content is in the content database. Don't bother trying to pick apart the database structure - there is an easier way:

You will need a WSS 3.0 farm, perhaps a clean install on a new machine. Then attach your mdf/ldf files in SQL Server (use Management Studio or T_SQL). Then create a web app in WSS and attach the database to the web app in SharePoint Central Administration. You will probably also need to change the site admin in Central Administration. You can then go back into your site and get at your aspx files.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I attached the database in SQL Management Studio, created a new web application, and associated the database to it. I was able to log into the Sharepoint web app that has the db attached to it, and while it gives me the basic structure of the backed up site, the content of lists is blank, that was the data I was really after (Announcements, tasks,etc exist as lists but are empty). How do I get access to this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to restore your site from the database. There is no need to extract files from the database. Once you set up a site, all content will appear again.

I haven't done this for some years, but articles like [KB 833797](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833797) show you the basics

It's also effectively the same as a SQL Server migration so [this too](http://msmvps.com/blogs/cgross/archive/2007/05/09/moving-a-wss-3-0-site-to-a-new-farm.aspx)

[And some Google links](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=active&q=sharepoint+3+restore+database&aq=3&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=19bff151c0ba26e)